# Mockito difference between annotations and method calls

Tags: java, testing, junit, annotations, mockito

I have a question about the use of Mockito in Java.
I will attach the 2 blocks of similar code:
The first one, which works great

```
package controller;

import model.DatabaseModel;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

public class TestController {

    JSONObject jsonObj1;
    JSONArray testArr;
    @Mock
    private DatabaseModel testDB;

    @InjectMocks
    private Controller controller;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        jsonObj1 = new JSONObject();
        jsonObj1.put("name", "Bar");
        testArr = new JSONArray();
        testArr.put(jsonObj1);
        when(testDB.getActivites()).thenReturn(testArr);
    }

    @Test
    public void testServerCon() {
        ArrayList<String> testServer = new ArrayList<>();
        testServer.add("Bar");
        assertEquals(testServer, controller.getAllActivites());
    }
}
```

And the second one, which doesn't really works:

```
package controller;

import model.DatabaseModel;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

public class TestController2 {
    JSONObject jsonObj1;
    JSONArray testArr;
    DatabaseModel testDB;
    Controller controller;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        jsonObj1=new JSONObject();
        jsonObj1.put("name", "Bar");
        testArr=new JSONArray();
        testArr.put(jsonObj1);
        controller=new Controller();
        testDB=mock(DatabaseModel.class);
        when(testDB.getActivites()).thenReturn(testArr);
        verify(testDB).getActivites();

    }

    @Test
    public void testServerCon(){

        ArrayList<String> testServer=new ArrayList<>();
        testServer.add("Bar");
        assertEquals(testServer, controller.getAllActivites());
    }
}
```

When I used the verify method for the second one, I get an error that the method never got called on the mock, So I wonder what am I missing?
I have looked up tutorials online, some use annotations and some use the method calls, but if I am not mistaken they should be the same, So what am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you doing a `verify` in the `setup` method in the second version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example the `@InjectMocks` annotation causes the instance of `Controller` to be *injected* with the mocked `DatabaseModel`.

In your second example, you construct the `Controller` like so ...

```
controller=new Controller();
```

... but you never inject the mocked `Database Model` into this instance of the `Controller`. So, when you invoke `controller.getAllActivites()` your controller never uses the mocked `DatabaseModel`. You can achieve the same outcome as that in the first example if you can inject the `DatabaseModel` into your `Controller`. For example:

```
testDB=mock(DatabaseModel.class);

// constructor injection
controller=new Controller(testDB);

// setter injection
controller=new Controller();
controller.setDatabaseModel(testDB);
```

Note: even if you remove `verify(testDB).getActivites()` from the setup method the test will fail its assertion unless you actualy provide the mocked `DatabaseModel` to the `controller`.

Comment: ... and as the other answer says, you should only `verify` after you have actually invoked the method-under-test

Comment: So, Do I have to use the @Inject annotation? or is there a method to this?

Comment: @BarLerer I have updated the answer to show you how to inject the `DatabaseModel` into the `Controller` in the second example.

Comment: Ok, So I see I must have a constructor that accepts the testDB or a setter.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a `verify` in the `setup` method in the second version...

```
@Before
public void setup() {

    jsonObj1=new JSONObject();
    jsonObj1.put("name", "Bar");
    testArr=new JSONArray();
    testArr.put(jsonObj1);
    controller=new Controller();
    testDB=mock(DatabaseModel.class);
    when(testDB.getActivites()).thenReturn(testArr);
    verify(testDB).getActivites(); // REMOVE THIS LINE

}
```

Nothing would have been called by this time, hence the error.

You probably want to move this line into your test method, for example...

```
@Test
public void testServerCon(){

    ArrayList<String> testServer=new ArrayList<>();
    testServer.add("Bar");
    assertEquals(testServer, controller.getAllActivites());
    verify(testDB).getActivites();
}
```

Comment: ...and as the other answer says, you actually need to inject your mock.